# Check if list of objects contains a String

Tags: java

I have the below class with the fields name and id -

```
    public class MyObj {
        private String name;
        private String id;
        //getters and setters + toString implementation
    }
```

In my main method, I am creating a list of `MyObj`and adding elements to the list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObj> myList = new ArrayList<MyObj>();
    MyObj myObj1 = new MyObj();
    myObj1.setName("test");
    myObj1.setId("123");
    myList.add(myObj1);

    MyObj myObj2 = new MyObj();
    myObj2.setName("testOne");
    myObj2.setId("456");
    myList.add(myObj2);
   }
```

When I iterate through the list, and print the contents, I have this -

```
    MyObj [name=test, id=123]
    MyObj [name=testOne, id=456]
```

I want to check if my List has a string. For example, if it contains name or id? When I use the contains method, it returns false. Clearly I am doing something wrong. How do I check if a list of objects has a string?

Comment: You need to override the `equals` and `hashcode` methods of `MyObj`.

Comment: I'm confused... Can you simplify your question?

Comment: If you already iterate through the list you hadn't the idea of using `entity.getName().equals(searchString)` and `entity.getId().equals(searchId)`?

Comment: I am not doing a equality check on the values (test 123, testOne,456), but rather on the fields name and id

Comment: @rickygrimes Isn't this what I wrote? Check the fields instead of using `list.contains()`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like Java8 Stream and filter, but if I understand your question (and the answers and comments) you want to get all the MyObj matching a criteria?

In that case, `equals` is not the way to do it. eg:

```
MyObj a = ...
a.setName("A");
a.equals("A"); // returns true
"A".equals(a); // returns false!
```

The javadoc of [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) says that:

> The equals method implements an equivalence relation on non-null
>   object references:
>
> - It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value x, x.equals(x) should return true.
> - **It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.**
> - It is transitive: for any non-null reference values x, y, and z, if x.equals(y) returns true and y.equals(z) returns true, then x.equals(z) should return true.
> - It is consistent: for any non-null reference values x and y, multiple invocations of x.equals(y) consistently return true or
>     consistently return false, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the objects is modified.
>     For any non-null reference value x, x.equals(null) should return false.

And in that case, you have a non symmetric equals (even if javadocs says it **should** be rather than it **must** be).

You can use filter, or better Java 8's `Stream`.

In pre Java 8, for loops, or external library such as Guava is the way to go.

The "simple" use case is the following:

```
List<MyObj> matching = new ArrayList<>();
for (MyObj o : list) {
  if (null != o.getName() || null != o.getId()) {
    matching.add(o);
  }
}
```

This says that you have either a `name` defined (eg: not `null`), either an `id`.

If you need to go further, with advanced criteria, you can do that:

```
interface Predicate<T> {
  boolean test(@Nullable T value);
}

public class Lists {
static <T> List<T> filter(List<? extends T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
  List<MyObj> matching = new ArrayList<>();
  for (MyObj o : list) {      
    if (predicate.test(o)) {
      matching.add(o);
    }
  }
  return matching;
}
}
```

And an example:

```
Lists.filter(listMyObj, new Predicate<MyObj>() {
  public boolean test(MyObj o) {
    return null != o.getName() || null != o.getId();
  }
});
```

But you should use Guava since it does the same, and better (my example is more or less what Guava does).

As for Java 8:

```
myList.stream()
      .filter(o -> null != o.getName() || null != o.getId())
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And I think you can do better using `MyObj::getName`/`getId` and some `Function` wrapper, to do the "isNull" test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement equals method in your MyObj

Comment: If its not implemented, can I not do it?

Comment: He wants to look for ids or names so equals won't really solve the problem

Comment: @rickygrimes it's not implemented obviously. `YOU` need to do it :)

Comment: That's not was equals is for. And read the Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29 : It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.